# How do I to change the Android Theme of a Xamarin project?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to change the Android's theme of a Xamarin project. To do this I'm changing the AndroidManifest.xml adding the clausule `<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" android:label="MyApp.Android"></application>` and erasing the `Theme = "@style/MainTheme"` in MainActivity.cs but it just crash and doesn't open the App.

How could I do this ?

Comment: Can you add relevant `adb logcat` regarding the crash? Chances are, you have something malformed in your AndroidManifest.xml or similar.

Comment: I would suggest you check adb logcat and output window you would probably get your answer there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Java inheritance from **AppCompatActivity** to **Activity**, then you will solve this issue.

Please take a look the following thread for detailed info:

[You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)